# How to assign external domain to the page of current website

Tags: php, laravel, dns, system-administration

Sorry if the question will seem little fuzzy and you will be tempted to down-vote it as soon as you read it. I am far from being an expert in system administration but I will try to explain the problem as clearly as I can.

I need to create a website where users can have profiles and attach an external domain to their profile page on this site. Let's say we have a site: 
myresume.com

User will register and create a profile and his url will look like:
myresume.com/username

The feature I need to add should enable user to point his domain to his profile url.

Is it possible via php as my whole application will be written in laravel 5.2?

I will probably need to have my nameservers or just give user the IP address which he needs to point his domain to but then I will need to fetch the domain from my side somehow and point it to the url (myresume.com/username). How can it be done?

If someone could give an explanation how it is done or at least point where to search for an answer it would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: I have flagged the question as 'too broad' because it can be done with multiple ways. If not, this belongs to Programmers StackExchange and not StackOverflow because I will be asking - what have you done so far? Though, before flagging, I have attempted to answer the question. Please find my answer below. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Could they just set up their domain to forward automatically to their profile on your website. Obviously this wouldn't preserve their domain name but rather redirect them to your website? Or are you wanting them to be able to go to example.com (which is their domain) and it serve the content of their user profile on `myresume.com/username`?

Comment: @Cherish I recommend you go read up on what is on-topic over at programmers.se.  This question would get closed very quickly over there.

Comment: Cherish and James, thank you for your answers. The process should be automated so the user should be able to manage it from the back end himself. If the user will attach example.com to his profile page, which will be site.com/profile than it should not be just a redirect but his domain should be displayed and if there will be other routes such as site.com/profile/item1 should have example.com/item1 one instead of profile. I am just trying to figure out the logic and once done i can research the steps of the process further myself and code it. Just need to figure out right direction.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze I have answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to know how Apache NGINX works.
2. You need to know what `$_SERVER['HOST']` is.
3. Logic to implement this.

This is how you will do it:

Host your app on a VPS / dedicated where your app is the 'default' with no other VirtualHost.
On your index.php file, `define` URL. If URL is set, let your Laravel's route choose which profile_id is matched with URL and then redirect the user to that URL or render the output.

Simple?

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)